# Wpf Application crashes without exception

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have an xaml file that contains two tab items.

At first it opens fine and when I switch tabs the application crashes with no exception.

The problem is not in the second tab because if I switch the tab items in the xaml file, it opens fine and crashes again when switching back.

The tab items contains a custom editor that contains a rich text box (each one of them) and they have the same loaded function (it's ok, I tested it).

Funny thing is when I add `visability="hidden"` to the second editor it opens with now problem.

HTML example:

```
<TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEditorView}">            
            <TabItem Header="first">
<editor:SourceCodeEditor x:Name="globalEditor" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Loaded="codeEditor_Loaded" SourceCodeDocumnet="{Binding Path=GlobalDocument, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="0 10" />                        
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="second">                
            <editor:SourceCodeEditor x:Name="monitorEditor" Loaded="codeEditor_Loaded" Grid.Column="2" SourceCodeDocumnet="{Binding Path=MonitorDocument, Mode=TwoWay}"  />         
            </TabItem>            
</TabControl>
```

I really don't know what to do!

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Breakpoint on the switching code?  Checked to make sure all possible debugging is enabled (native code)?  It looks like you're doing dynamic compiling, have you setup proper error catching for that?

Comment: when i see a crash with no exception, i think first about a thread issue, like an event trying to access a resource not on its thread or like.

Comment: Possibly, though in my experience, WPF always throws an exception if that type of error occurs with WPF managed resources.

Comment: Thank you very much.

I solved it...

problem was that the custom editor  inherits from richtextbox and i had a "this.focus()" in the constructor.

it crashed the program with no exception.... very hard to find.



i still don't understand few things:

1. why it crashed with no error and even didnt fail on try\catch?

2. why you can't put focus on a richtextbox constructor that found in a tab item because it opened fine for the first time and crashed on switch tabs...



thank you....

Comment: it is very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673421/wpf-crashing-by-environment-failfast