# WPF crashing by Environment.FailFast

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on WPF application built for Kiosk (Touch Screen). We build Virtual Keyboard for ourselves.

There is one screen we list some items (max of 4 items) using DataGrid control which has a TextBox. The virtual keyboard shows on focus (thats how it built).

When we make selecting different items randomly, the application crashes without reaching the generic exception handler. This issue is repeatable on Touch screen, but not in regular screens. The event log shows the below,

```
Application: CashNGo.WPF.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string
message).
Message: Unrecoverable system error.
Stack:
   at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String)
   at MS.Internal.Invariant.FailFast(System.String, System.String)
   at MS.Internal.Invariant.Assert(Boolean, System.String)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextStore.VerifyTextStoreConsistency()
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextStore.GrantLock()
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextStore.GrantLockWorker(LockFlags)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextStore.RequestLock(LockFlags, Int32 ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods+ITextStoreACPSink.OnSelectionChange()
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextStore.OnSelectionChanged()
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.System.Windows.Documents.ITextRange.NotifyChanged(Boolean,
Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextRangeBase.EndChange(System.Windows.Documents.ITextRange,
Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Documents.TextSelection.System.Windows.Documents.ITextRange.Select(System.Windows.Documents.ITextPointer,
System.Windows.Documents.ITextPointer)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Select(Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.set_CaretIndex(Int32)
   at Common.Controls.SoftKeyboard.<.cctor>b__1c(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)
   at System.Windows.Input.DelegateCommand`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].Execute(System.__Canon)
   at Common.Controls.SoftKeyboard+<>c__DisplayClass5.<SoftKeyboardFocus_Changed>b__0()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Action, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
System.Threading.CancellationToken, System.TimeSpan)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Action, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority)
   at Common.Extensions+<>c__DisplayClass1.<DelayedInvoke>b__0(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object,
Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate,
System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
  at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback,
System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback,
System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback,
System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean
ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object,
Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate,
System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority,
System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at CashNGo.WPF.App.Main()
```

I did some search and found http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dfbd2526-8953-4ce8-97c2-43246fd251c0/wpf-framework-crashing-on-setting-foxus-in-textbox?forum=wpf which is exactly the same exception.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: As the trace does not seems to have any interesting point. So could you post a working sample which can reproduce the same?

Comment: Just disable a service called "Tablet PC Input Service", and see what happens.

Comment: @pushpraj Sample is not possible, as it needs lots of styles and get the Virtual Keyboard up and running. We did some finding. I turned off the VK, and the crash is gone.

Comment: @YuliamChandra did you meant "TabletInputService"? I will try tomorrow as I am home now. Thank you.

Comment: you will lose the touch screen ability, but most of my wpf problems were cause by that service..

Comment: @YuliamChandra Its all right. We have Virtual Keyboard for ourselves. Will update tomorrow

Comment: @YuliamChandra The stopping the service stopped the crash. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off a windows service called.

```
Tablet PC Input Service
```

Comment: Of course, on a tablet this isn't a great idea. Any work arounds or fixes that still let the user type would be awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Disabling the Windows service fixed the issue in my case too. On my Windows 8.1 Pro the service is called "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service"

Comment: Any more details as to why?